# Prove $\int_{-\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{1}{4}} \left(\left(H_{x+\frac{1}{4}}-H_{x-\frac{1}{4}}\right) \cos (2 \pi x)+\pi \right) \, dx=\text{Si}(\pi )$

Tags: definite-integrals, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

I recently stumbled upon a curious relationship between harmonic numbers and the Wilbraham-Gibbs constant:

$$\int_{-\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{1}{4}} \left(\left(H_{x+\frac{1}{4}}-H_{x-\frac{1}{4}}\right) \cos (2 \pi  x)+\pi \right) \, dx=\text{Si}(\pi )$$

Where $H_n$ is the $nth$ harmonic number, and $\mathrm{Si}(\pi)$ is the sine integral of $\pi$ (Wilbraham-Gibbs constant).

Is this an expected result, and if not, is it possible to prove? I have confirmed equivalency up to 40,000 digits.

Comment: The expression $H_{x+\frac14}-H_{x-\frac14}$ brings to mind the [functional equation](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/266748) of the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), especially in light of the relationship between [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the relation between the Harmonic numbers and digamma function, namely $H_{x} = \gamma + \psi(x +1)$, the relation between the digamma function and the gamma function, 
$$\psi(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \, \ln(\Gamma(x)),$$
and the integrals:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi \, t}{2}\right) \, \ln\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right) \, dt &= - \frac{2}{\pi} \, \left[ Si\left(\frac{\pi(1-t)}{2}\right) - 
Si\left(\frac{\pi(1+t)}{2}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right) \, \ln\left(\frac{1 + t}{1-t}\right) \right]_{0}^{1} \\
&= \frac{2}{\pi} \, Si(\pi) 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi \, t}{2}\right) \, \ln\left(cot\left(\frac{\pi(1+t)}{4}\right)\right) \, dt &= (-1) \, \left[ t + \frac{2}{\pi} \, \cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right) \, \ln\left( 
\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{4}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{4}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{4}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{4}\right)} \right)\right]_{0}^{1} \\
&= -1
\end{align}
the following is obtained.

\begin{align}
I &= \int_{-1/4}^{1/4} \left[ \pi + \left(H_{x+1/4} - H_{x-1/4}\right) \, \cos(2\pi x) \right] \, dx \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} + \int_{-1/4}^{1/4} \left[ \psi\left(x + \frac{5}{4}\right) - \psi\left(x + \frac{3}{4}\right) \right] \, \cos(2 \pi x) \, dx 
\end{align}
Using integration by parts yields
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi \, \int_{-1/4}^{1/4} \sin(2\pi t) \, \ln\left( \frac{\Gamma\left(t + \frac{5}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(t + \frac{3}{4}\right)}\right) \, dt \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2} \, \int_{-1}^{1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right) \, \ln\left( \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{5+t}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left( \frac{3+t}{4}\right)}\right) \, dt \text{ (obtained by setting $t \to t/4$) } \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \, \left[ 1 + \int_{0}^{1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right) \, 
\ln\left[\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{5+t}{4}\right) \, \Gamma\left(\frac{3-t}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left( \frac{3+t}{4}\right) \, \Gamma\left(\frac{5-t}{4}\right)} \right] \, dt \right] \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \, \left[ 1 + \int_{0}^{1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right) \, 
\ln\left[\frac{1+t}{1-t} \, cot\left(\frac{\pi (1+t)}{4}\right) \right] \, dt \right] \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \, \left[ 1 + \frac{2}{\pi} \, Si(\pi) -1 \right] \\
&= Si(\pi).
\end{align}
Hence,
$$\int_{-1/4}^{1/4} \left[ \pi + \left(H_{x+1/4} - H_{x-1/4}\right) \, \cos(2\pi x) \right] \, dx = Si(\pi).$$

Comment: This looks good, checking each step now and will report back!

Comment: OK, the only thing that's unclear to me is LogGamma vs. the natural log of Gamma. Are they equivalent in this case or are there assumptions?

$\text{log$\Gamma $}\left(t+\frac{5}{4}\right)-\text{log$\Gamma $}\left(t+\frac{3}{4}\right)=\log \frac{ \Gamma \left(t+\frac{5}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(t+\frac{3}{4}\right)}$

Comment: @DavidScottKirby In this case the digamma function is defined by use of the natural log (base e). The use of "Log" is sometimes used in the notation for the digamma function, but is not base 10 (or other base). For this problem, and others, it is often useful to define the notation to be used.

Comment: The famous functional equation correlating [Riemann's $\zeta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) to [Euler's $\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) can be written as $$\frac{\Gamma\Big(\tfrac14+x\Big)}{\Gamma\Big(\tfrac14-x\Big)} ~=~ \pi^{2x}\cdot\frac{\zeta\Big(\tfrac12-2x\Big)}{\zeta\Big(\tfrac12+2x\Big)}.$$ Taking the logarithm of both sides and then differentiating ultimately yields an equivalent expression for $H_{x+\frac14}-H_{x-\frac14}~$

Comment: Thank you Lucian for your answer. It triggered a year of learning new things to try and understand it. I think it's really beautiful.